# Set text for Edittext on a custom alert dialog

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

I have code below

Layout for a alert dialog with 4 Edittext

alert_edit_information1.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Name"
    android:id="@+id/editTextInformationName" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Address"
    android:id="@+id/editTextInformationAddress" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Phone"
    android:id="@+id/editTextInformationPhones"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Company Name"
    android:id="@+id/editTextInformationCompanyName" />
```

Click on an relative layout to pop a alert dialog

```
 relativeLayout1.setOnClickListener(new AdapterView.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
             alert.setTitle("Alert Dialog With EditText"); //Set Alert dialog title
             alert.setView(R.layout.alert_edit_information1);//Set 4 edittext to alert dialog
             editTextName = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editTextInformationName); //error posible here
             editTextName.setText("Name here",TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE); //error here
             alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {  } 
            }); //End of alert.setPositiveButton
alert.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            // Canceled.
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });//End of alert.setNegativeButton
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
                    alertDialog.show();

    }
        });
```

Error log

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence, android.widget.TextView$BufferType)' on a null object reference
```

Am I initializing EditText right? 
Is this line good?

editTextName = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editTextInformationName);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have done like below.

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
// ...Irrelevant code for customizing the buttons and title
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout. alert_edit_information1, null);
dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

EditText editText = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.editTextInformationName);
editText.setText("test label");
AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

**Don't**

```
  editTextName = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.editTextInformationName);
  editTextName.setText("Name here",TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
```

**Do**

You should pass View's Object.

```
 editTextName = (EditText) alert.findViewById(R.id.editTextInformationName);
 editTextName.setText("Name here");
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't directly set the view for AlertDialog like

```
alert.setView(R.layout.alert_edit_information1);
```

use local view variable like

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout. alert_edit_information1, null);
```

and then use

```
alert.setView(view);
```

now you can you init a edittext with the of v -> view.

```
editTextName = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.editTextInformationName);
editTextName.setText("Name here",TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
```